# Is the effect of friction force transferred INSTANTLY in this case?

Tags: classical-mechanics, friction, string, causality

I read on a website that if the sun is removed from its position then it would take some time for the earth to feel the effect i.e. flying off tangentially from the orbit.

In a slightly different case, suppose I have a rope with a bob at one of its ends and the other end is in my hand. I can hold the rope tightly because of the friction force between my hand and the rope and can rotate the rope easily without slipping off the rope because of friction. But suppose friction force vanishes (by any means) then from experience we know that the body flies off tangentially.

Does it mean that the effect is transferred **INSTANTLY** and if not what is the cause of the delay?

Correct me if I am wrong somewhere.

Comment: You might like [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uiyMuHuCFo4&t=156s). But to get to an actual comment here, your scenarios are somewhat ill-defined and inconsistent. For example, you talk about a rope with Bob, then then talk about a ball. Then you switch from losing friction to suddenly changing the length of ropes. Can you please clean up your question to focus on a single, well-defined scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does it mean that the effect is transferred **INSTANTLY** and if not can we calculate the delay ??

Well, there is more than one effect, and different effects happen at different times.

First, instantly when you release the friction on the rope the center of mass of the system consisting of the rope + the bob begins to travel tangentially.

Second, the tension in the part of the rope immediately adjacent to your hand begins to relax. This relaxation of the tension propagates as a longitudinal wave through the material of the rope. The speed of propagation of this wave is the speed of sound in the material of the rope.

Third, the bob will continue to move in the circular path until that mechanical wave propagates all the way to the bob. While the wave has not reached the bob, the rope at the bob is still under tension and therefore the bob continues to accelerate. Only once the wave reaches the bob and the tension is relieved will the bob travel in a straight line. Note that this does not contradict the fact that the center of mass of the bob + rope system immediately travels in a straight line.

Here is a good pair of videos which demonstrates this principle using gravity rather than centripetal motion:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eCMmmEEyOO0

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JsytnJ_pSf8

Comment: Thanks for those links . But nothing could travel faster than light , so how or why does th center of mass responds instantly ??

Comment: It does not travel faster than light, rotational speed instantly becomes linear speed when centripetal force stops opposing centrifugal force.

Comment: @Ankit no information travels faster than light. In fact in this scenario no information travels faster than the speed of sound. The center of mass is not an object. It is a calculation based on the entire extended system. Part of the extended system (the rope) is touching the hand so the distance is 0. That portion of the system can respond instantly and therefore so can any quantity (like the COM) which is calculated based at least in part on that portion of the system.

Comment: @Dale but center of mass is not just a mathematical model rather it has a physical significance.

Comment: So shouldn't we consider the effects on it ??

Comment: @Ankit I never said it had no physical significance, and we already did consider the effects on it: it instantaneously stops accelerating as I already explained. Comments are not intended for discussions. You seem to want to carry on long conversations in comments after receiving answers, which is against the purpose of a Q&A site. You may find a discussion forum like physicsforums.com more conducive to what you want.

Comment: @Dale I just want to know everything  completely that's why I ask in the comments.

Comment: @Ankit I can see that, but that is not the way a Q&A site is supposed to work. You should go to a discussion site where the format *encourages* the question/follow-up/discussion approach. That style just doesn’t fit here

Comment: @Dale Ok. That's my fault.

Answer (score 0):

> All models are wrong.  Some are useful

The effect is not transferred instantly.  It takes some time.  We often choose to model it as "instant" because that is close enough to get very accurate predictions of what happens.

When you talk about the effect of the sun being removed from orbit, you are talking about distances where the speed of light is a very major player in what is going on.  Any model dealing with orbital distances needs to account for the speed of light.

In your case with a rope and a bob at the end, you don't specify the length of the rope.  But given that you imply that we use human intuition, its probably a short rope.  Perhaps 1 meter?  On a 1 meter scale, the speed of light lets information propagate in 3.33564095 ns.  To put it on more useful terms, that's 0.00000000333564095 seconds.  That's short.  Really short.  The nice simple model you were using doesn't operate at that sort of fidelity.

We call this transmission of force 'instant' as a surrogate for the truth. Its a force that is transmitted so astonishingly fast that the model you are using can't even account for details that are that fast.  If you watch any [slow motion](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vPBM0g9usMs) videos, you'll see the sorts of astonishing things that occur on the microsecond timescale.  This is quite literally a thousand times shorter than that!

At these timescales, we have to toss out a lot of simplifications.  For example, you had a comment stream about centers of mass, and how they are not "physical" but they are "meaningful."  For a body that you can treat as rigid, they are very meaningful.  But if a body isn't rigid, their value gets more murky.  If some atoms of an object are in the light cone of an event, and some are not, you can still calculate a COM, it's just not useful for predicting what happens on those timescales.

I highly recommend the VSauce video, [What Is the Speed of Dark?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JTvcpdfGUtQ).  It covers some fun examples of how our meaningful mathematical concepts, like "darkness," can do things that physical objects cannot.